# Undesired Checkout Resources pop up in CCRC integrated with VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clearcase-remote-client

I have clearcase integrated with Visual Studio 2008. Everytime, I open a solution, I get Checkout Resources pop ups for the solution file and the project files within. I have to click on 'Cancel' several times before my solution is loaded.

Also when I build the project, I get the checkout resources pop up.

This is really annoying.

Anyone with a solution to prevent these unrequired Checkout Resources pop ups?

Thanks.

Comment: I am hoping that, by adding *manually* the `.sln` file to a `.ccexclude` file, the CC integration plugin would ignore it, even though you would still be able to checkout it manually outside from the CC integration.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to:

- add that solution file to the [**`.ccexclude`** file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21129630) (to make it ignored by the cc-VS2008 integration)
- checkout/checking said solution file only *outside* the integration (in a full CC client, not from the VS GUI): the reasoning being "you do not have to change that solution file all that often"

Notes:

- I am not familiar with VS projects, so I could be wrong in the update frequency of a solution file.
- this would solve at least unsolicited checkout only for that file.

Comment: How should I exclude the .sln file? I am not getting the option in CLearCase integrated with VS.Net.